# Quarkus не поддерживает Lombok? / Qarkus + Lombok = cannot find symbol

Tags: dependency-injection, lombok, quarkus

Случилась следующая беда, перешёл я на Quarkus и осознал что он не очень хочет работать с lombok

На код:

```
@Builder
public class ApiParam {
    private long user_id;
    private int random_id;
    private String message;
```

при запуске Quarkus я получаю следующее:

```
...ResponseManager.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
        ApiParam param = ApiParam.builder()
                                 ^
  symbol:   method builder()
  location: class VkApiParam
```

На сайте Quarkus`а я читал что он использует какую-то хитрую систему DI и в нем обращение к полям

```
   object.id
```

эквивалентно

```
   object.getId()
```

Но как по мне это извращение, да и к тому же вышеописанный builder не работает (такая же история с @Getter и @Setter), находил кто-то решение данной проблемы, или это прикол Quarkus который не лечится?

Answer (score 0):

Решение оказалось довольно простым, достаточно правильно имплементировать lombok

```
compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.28'
annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.28'
//Для тестов
testCompileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.28' 
testAnnotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.28'
```

нежели просто

```
implementation 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.28'
```